# HighLight multiple words in the after rendering the html in the screen

Tags: reactjs

Need to Highlight multiple words. It should not highlight any of HTML tags or HTML attributes in the HTML code based on the input received.

Simply put want to implement the CTRL+F function Within in  my project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It will need application level filtering.

When you receive the document or comment or any kind of text, check if you have something in the search field.

If Yes, find and replace the contents of text with special HTML & Class to highlight specific part.

You can check the implementation of common React Autocomplete libraries. The highlight is in the list but you can use same approach in the Global manner.